# What in next step after construct json file?

Tags: json

Dears , 
After construct json file of sensor what must I do ? 
Is it upload into server side platform or cloud hosted platform  ? 
Please advice

Comment: @Jogngladstone: sounds like and interesting project! Can you please provide more detail? What is your end goal?

Comment: Would you mind giving us more inforamation so the question gets sense? Welcome to SO, and please [read about asking questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), that will help you.

Comment: Hi , Actually I was new in this system , so I need to know after construct xml or json file from luvit-red configuration tool what is next step must do  to monitor the data ?